# How do I move items in the navigation bar using Bootstrap version 4.3.1

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having trouble in aligning the content of the navigation bar. I am trying to right align the contents of the menu using the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Sample Application</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="Center">Sample Application</h1>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md " style="background-color:#993300">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto ">
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Help!", "Help", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand", @style = "color:white" })
        </li>
    </ul>

</nav>

@RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the output.
[image]

I would like to move Help towards left as shown with the arrow. How do i accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: in `<ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto ">` replace `ml-auto` with `position-relative` and use css to set `left:75%` or whatever works for you

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap your navbar contents in a `container` it will restrict the width to the container width. and bring them in some.  If you want a specific right margin, you would have to define that yourself. You should also add the `nav-item` class to your li elements and `nav-link` class to your `a` tag.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<h1 align="Center">Sample Application</h1>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark" style="background-color:#993300">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto ">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Help!</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **mr-auto** for nav-item in the left side

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<h1 align="Center">Sample Application</h1>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark" style="background-color:#993300">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help!</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: But, that is not my requirement. I just want the nav-item to move slightly towards left side and not completely to the end. The answer below worked for me.